# Ibid is not working locally with biblatex-chicago

Tags: biber, biblatex-chicago, notes

I'm using the notes style of biblatex-chicago, but stangely Ibids are being printed on Overleaf, but not my local installation (TeXlive with TeXstudio on Windows 10). Footnote 2 is "Chaney, 50" on my local machine but "Ibid., 50" on Overleaf. Maybe something is wrong with my installation or the way I'm calling Biber (tools menu in TeXstudio)?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

I am citing the Chaney here.\autocite{chaney} Now I am citing the Chaney again.\autocite[50]{chaney} This is a citation of the Johnston.\autocite[56]{johnston} Now I'm citing the Chaney again.\autocite[42]{chaney}

\end{document}
```

and here's my bib file:

```
@phdthesis{chaney, 
    title={Four motets from the Florilegium portense}, 
    author={Chaney, Mark Allen}, 
    year={2007},
    school={Ohio State University},
    keywords={Secondary},
    shorttitle={Four motets}
}

@article{johnston, 
    title={Polyphonic keyboard accompaniment in the early Baroque: an alternative to basso continuo}, 
    volume={26}, 
    number={1}, journal={Early Music}, 
    author={Johnston, G.}, 
    year={1998}, 
    pages={51–64},
    keywords={Primary}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set the option `useibid` to `true`. The revision history in the `biblatex-chicago` documentation explains

> [2.0: Released April 20, 2020] The 17th edition of the *Manual* no longer encourages use of *ibid.* to replace repeated citations of the same work in the notes & bibliography style, preferring instead to use the author's name alone, along with any pagenumber(s). If you wish
> to continue using *ibid.* in that style, you need to set the new option `useibid=true`
> when loading `biblatex-chicago` in your preamble.

The options `usebib` is documented as

> In a change to previous recommendations, the 17th edition of the *Manual* “discourages  the use of *ibid.*,” preferring instead a shortened reference with only the author’s name
> (14.34). `biblatex-chicago` now implements these recommendations by default, including the repetition of page references even when they’re exactly the same as the previous note. If you prefer to continue using `ibid.`, then set `useibid=true` in your document
> preamble and you’ll get the traditional behavior.

This also explains why you see different results locally and on Overleaf. It appears that your local installation has the newest version of `biblatex-chicago`, but that Overleaf are lagging behind a bit.

With that option enabled you get

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,useibid=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{chaney, 
  title      = {Four motets from the Florilegium portense}, 
  author     = {Chaney, Mark Allen}, 
  year       = {2007},
  school     = {Ohio State University},
  keywords   = {Secondary},
  shorttitle = {Four motets}
}
@article{johnston, 
  title    = {Polyphonic keyboard accompaniment in the early Baroque: an alternative to basso continuo}, 
  volume   = {26}, 
  number   = {1},
  journal  = {Early Music}, 
  author   = {Johnston, G.}, 
  year     = {1998}, 
  pages    = {51–64},
  keywords = {Primary}
 }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
I am citing the Chaney here.\autocite{chaney}
Now I am citing the Chaney again.\autocite[50]{chaney}
This is a citation of the Johnston.\autocite[56]{johnston}
Now I'm citing the Chaney again.\autocite[42]{chaney}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2. Ibid., 50.]

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know about that new Chicago Manual recommendation, so that's doubly helpful.